# How to print out 2d ascii letters horizontally

Tags: go, data-structures, struct, ascii, ascii-art

I have mapped user input with 2d ascii letters and now I am trying to print out ascii letters below horizontally, so they could be printed side by side not top down as they are right now. Letter height is 8 lines and width varies. I run the code `go run . "hello"` Could really appriciate some help. I have tried to loop over the Table, but no success and haveb't been able to figure out yet how to print letters side by side.

```
 _      
| |     
| |__   
|  _ \  
| | | | 
|_| |_| 
        
        
       
       
  ___  
 / _ \ 
|  __/ 
 \___| 
       
       
 _  
| | 
| | 
| | 
| | 
|_| 
    
    
 _  
| | 
| | 
| | 
| | 
|_| 
    
    
        
        
  ___   
 / _ \  
| (_) | 
 \___/
```

I use struct for mapping and storying data on that format below:

```
{h 104 [[ ] [_] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]] []}
{h 104 [[|] [ ] [|] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]] []}
{h 104 [[|] [ ] [|] [_] [_] [ ] [ ] [ ]] []}
{h 104 [[|] [ ] [ ] [_] [ ] [\] [ ] [ ]] []}
{h 104 [[|] [ ] [|] [ ] [|] [ ] [|] [ ]] []}
{h 104 [[|] [_] [|] [ ] [|] [_] [|] [ ]] []}
{h 104 [[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]] []}
{h 104 [[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]] []}
{e 101 [[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]] []}
{e 101 [[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]] []}
{e 101 [[ ] [ ] [_] [_] [_] [ ] [ ]] []}
{e 101 [[ ] [/] [ ] [_] [ ] [\] [ ]] []}
{e 101 [[|] [ ] [ ] [_] [_] [/] [ ]] []}
{e 101 [[ ] [\] [_] [_] [_] [|] [ ]] []}
{e 101 [[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]] []}
{e 101 [[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]] []}
{l 108 [[ ] [_] [ ] [ ]] []}
{l 108 [[|] [ ] [|] [ ]] []}
{l 108 [[|] [ ] [|] [ ]] []}
{l 108 [[|] [ ] [|] [ ]] []}
{l 108 [[|] [ ] [|] [ ]] []}
{l 108 [[|] [_] [|] [ ]] []}
{l 108 [[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]] []}
{l 108 [[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]] []}
{l 108 [[ ] [_] [ ] [ ]] []}
{l 108 [[|] [ ] [|] [ ]] []}
{l 108 [[|] [ ] [|] [ ]] []}
{l 108 [[|] [ ] [|] [ ]] []}
{l 108 [[|] [ ] [|] [ ]] []}
{l 108 [[|] [_] [|] [ ]] []}
{l 108 [[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]] []}
{l 108 [[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]] []}
{o 111 [[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]] []}
{o 111 [[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]] []}
{o 111 [[ ] [ ] [_] [_] [_] [ ] [ ] [ ]] []}
{o 111 [[ ] [/] [ ] [_] [ ] [\] [ ] [ ]] []}
{o 111 [[|] [ ] [(] [_] [)] [ ] [|] [ ]] []}
{o 111 [[ ] [\] [_] [_] [_] [/] [ ] [ ]] []}
{o 111 [[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]] []}
{o 111 [[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]] []}
```

My code ascii.go:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

type letter struct {
    Letter string
    Ascii  int
    Table  [][]string
    Color  []string
}

func mapFont(font string) ([]letter, error) {
    readFile, err := os.ReadFile(font)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("could not read the content in the file: %v", err)
    }
    slice := strings.Split(string(readFile), "\n")

    letters := make([]letter, 0)
    index := 31

    for _, row := range slice {
        if row == "" {
            index++
            continue
        }

        grid := make([][]string, 0)

        for _, char := range row {
            grid = append(grid, []string{string(char)})
        }

        letters = append(letters, letter{
            Letter: string(index),
            Ascii:  index,
            Table:  grid,
        })
    }
    return letters, nil
}

func mapInput(input string, letters []letter) ([]letter, error) {
    lines := strings.Split(input, "\\n")
    output := make([]letter, 0)

    for _, line := range lines {
        characters := []rune(line)

        if line != "" {
            for _, ch := range characters {
                if ch >= 32 && ch <= 126 {
                    for _, v := range letters {
                        if rune(v.Ascii) == ch {
                            output = append(output, v)
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    return nil, fmt.Errorf("input includes non ascii character(s), please use ascii character(s)")
                }
            }
        } else {
            output = append(output, letter{})
        }
    }
    return output, nil
}

func printLettersSideBySide(mapping []letter) {
    output := ""
    for i := 0; i < len(mapping); i++ {
        for j := 0; j < len(mapping[i].Table); j++ {
            output = output + strings.Join(mapping[i].Table[j], "")
        }
        output = output + "\n"
    }

    fmt.Println(output)
}
```

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    args := os.Args

    banners := "banner/standard.txt"
    str := args[1]

    letter, _ := mapFont(banners)
    mapping, _ := mapInput(str, letter)

    printLettersSideBySide(mapping)

    for _, item := range mapping {
        fmt.Println(item)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Leaving answer to others who may need it:

Was able to solve it by making data structure for Table in type letter simpler. Replaced [][]string with []string in and made changes in mapFont function where I used that struct. Then I added new function for printing letters horizontally.

ascii.go

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)


type letter struct {
    Letter string
    Ascii  int
    Table  []string
}

func mapFont(font string) ([]letter, error) {
    readFile, err := os.ReadFile(font)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("could not read the content in the file: %v", err)
    }
    slice := strings.Split(string(readFile), "\n")

    letters := make([]letter, 0)
    index := 31

    for _, row := range slice {

        if row == "" {
            index++
            continue
        }

        grid := make([]string, 0)

        for _, char := range row {
            grid = append(grid, string(char))
        }

        letters = append(letters, letter{
            Letter: string(index),
            Ascii:  index,
            Table:  grid,
        })
    }
    return letters, nil
}

func mapInput(input string, letters []letter) ([]letter, error) {
    lines := strings.Split(input, "\\n")
    output := make([]letter, 0)

    for _, line := range lines {
        characters := []rune(line)

        if line != "" {
            for _, ch := range characters {
                if ch >= 32 && ch <= 126 {
                    for _, v := range letters {
                        if rune(v.Ascii) == ch {
                            output = append(output, v)
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    return nil, fmt.Errorf("input includes non ascii character(s), please use ascii character(s)")
                }
            }
        } else {
            output = append(output, letter{})
        }
    }
    return output, nil
}

func printInput(str string, letter []letter) []string {
    var pixelRows []string

    for row := 0; row < 8; row++ {
        pixelRow := ""

        for letterIndex := 0; letterIndex < len(str); letterIndex++ {
   
            character, _ := mapInput(string(str[letterIndex]), letter)

            for column := 0; column < len(character[row].Table); column++ 
                pixelRow = pixelRow + character[row].Table[column]

            }

        }
        pixelRows = append(pixelRows, pixelRow)
    }
    return pixelRows
}
```

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

)

func main() {
    args := os.Args

    banners := "banner/standard.txt"
    str := args[1]

    letter, _ := mapFont(banners)
    sentence, _ := mapInput(str, letter)
    output := printInput(str, sentence)
    
    for _, v := range output {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
    
}
```

Output:

```
❯ go run . "hello"
 _              _   _          
| |            | | | |         
| |__     ___  | | | |   ___   
|  _ \   / _ \ | | | |  / _ \  
| | | | |  __/ | | | | | (_) | 
|_| |_|  \___| |_| |_|  \___/
```